# Is there a way to keep the VS 2010 VB.NET IDE from doing things that it thinks I want it to do?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Do this in VS 2010 with VB.NET:

1. On a blank line, type anything that isn't a variable, property, method, etc.  I will use `woo` as an example.
2. Hit Enter or move the cursor up or down a line.
3. VS will add parenthesis to the end of it, turning it into `woo()`.
4. Annoying, isn't it?  Now insert `foo` in front of `woo()`, separated by a space like this: `foo woo()`.
5. Move the cursor up or down (don't use Enter).  VS turns it into `foo(woo())`, somehow drawing the conclusion that you want to pass `woo()` through `foo()`.  What gave it that idea?

I know that the IDE isn't a text editor, but there are many times when I will want to paste in some text from a business requirements document or even some SQL and then comment it out after the fact.  c# is great for this since it never assumes that I am trying to do anything, but the VB.NET IDE ends up parsing the holy love out of whatever block of text I paste into it and I end up having to edit out everything it added in.

Why does it do this?  Can I tell it not to?

Comment: `<trolling>` Why don't you use VIM? `</trolling>`

Comment: @SteveB Stop trying to troll me and troll me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unselect `Pretty listing (reformatting) of code`. You can find this under: `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> VB Specific`

Comment: @oscilatingcretin happy to have been helpful.

Comment: Hmmm... I seem to have thrown out the baby with the bathwater on this one.  It seems that that option does more than just keep VS from adding parenthesis to stuff.  It also appears to keep the IDE from preserving indents when I press Enter.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Apparently the Tabs property in VB is linked to the "Pretty listing". You have to "override" the Tabs value via "All Languages". Under Text Editor -> All Languages -> Tabs, select "Smart" as Indenting.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I have still observed a limitation. If you do what I proposed in my previous comment and press enter, the new line will get the right margin. BUT if you write a line starting from the left border and press enter, its marging will not be corrected. This behaviour (correcting the margin of the current line) does seem to be associated with "Pretty listing". The reason why it is not managed by the Tab option for all the languages is that, for example, C# does not have this behaviour; in C#, to correct the current line you have to write ";" at the end (enter doesn't trigger it).

Comment: @oscilatingcretin PS: in C# this is under Formatting -> Indentation (Indent Block Contents). VB summarises the C# categories "Advanced", "IntelliSense" and "Formatting" (including "General", "Indentation", "New Lines", "Spacing" and "Wrapping"); into one category: "VB Specific" (and quite a few C# formatting properties into a single property called "Pretty listing (reformatting) of code"). It is the VB-way of doing things: "let us take control of everything and just enjoy coding" (some times nice, some times a bit annoying) ;)